# What is meaning of %* at the end of the script command?

Tags: windows

I saw a [blog](http://geekrandomnotes.blogspot.com/2011/11/powershell-and-bamboo.html). It has a dos command.

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "echo Hesus | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe %*"
```

I don't know why it has %* at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

The % operator passes any commandline argument given by the .cmd file into your script.

%0 means: the filename of the script itself
%1 till %9 are 9 arguments following.

%* means, all arguments passed in order of appearance. This is basically used when you want to execute several commands prior to executing the main command with all the parameters.

## Examples

Lets assume your cmd file is called test.cmd and its located in c:\temp.

The script is written as follows:

```
echo This script is: %0
echo Parameter 1 given is: %1
echo Parameters 2 and 3 are: %2 %3
echo.
echo All parameters are: %*
```

You type in the following command at the commandline:

```
C:\TEMP>test 1 2 3
```

The output on the screen will be:

```
This script is: C:\TEMP\test.cmd
Parameter 1 given is: 1
Parameters 2 and 3 are: 2 3

All parameters are: 1 2 3

C:\TEMP>_
```

Comment: Thanks, by the way. There is a `/c` after `cmd.exe`. What is that? Can we just use a simple command. `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe  "C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"`

Comment: `cmd /c` means: execute the command after `/c` and then terminate cmd.exe (kills the window) `/k` is the same as `/c` but instead, the cmd window remains open. Open a command prompt and type in `cmd /?` for all possible parameters.